# htaccess and url encoding ? Escaping + and &

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, encoding, url-rewriting

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (?!^infos/)^(.+?)/?$ /dl.php?f=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This htaccess is used to make user-friendly URL for downloads.

```
example.com/some_file_to_download.zip
```

will redirect to the download page at

```
example.com/dl.php?f=some_file_to_download.zip
```

Problem is that when the filename contains special characters like `+` or `&`, it will mess up the GET variable of `dl.php`

Example of a problematic URL:

```
example.com/file&special+characters
```

will redirect to

```
example.com/dl.php?f=file&special+chracters
```

So we have a problem here.

How can i escape those special characters in my htaccess file ?
I have no control over the original URL (before it is being redirected to `dl.php`) so i can't just use php to urlencode.

Comment: Hi Winston, I've encountered a very similar situation as you and was wondering if you solved the problem?

Comment: You can add the [B] flag to URL-encode the back-references as they're used.   This will resolve the unencoded ampersand, but _everything_ you capture will be url-encoded which is not suitable for your large capture.

Ideally you would not copy from the path to the query string.  Using PATH_INFO on the other end is much safer.   The only way to do this reliably is to use an external rewritemap program that is ware of _where_ you substitute into so it can decide that / does not need substitution, but & does.